# What kind of API's are behind SAML, oAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect?

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, openid, saml

Can someone explain how the backend of this protocols/standards works? I know they work on HTTP but I am not sure if they are REST or SOAP services.

This is confusing a bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth and OIDC are REST APIs.

SAML precedes this and doesn't really have an API profile but I have seen SOAP being used.